# Can't access class @property from other @property in Cython

Tags: cython

I'm learning Cython and ran into the following weird bug

```
import cython

cdef double MILES_PER_KILOMETER = 0.621371

cdef class Distance:
    cdef double distance, miles, meters, km

    def __cinit__(self, double distance) -> None:
        self.distance = distance

    @property
    def miles(self):
        print(self.km)
        return self.km * MILES_PER_KILOMETER

    @property
    def meters(self):
        print(self.km)
        return self.km * 1000.0

    @property
    def km(self):
        return self.distance
```

Running this I get

```
In [2]: from distance_compiled import Distance

In [3]: Distance(42)
Out[3]: <distance_compiled.Distance at 0x7f7a132bc5a0>

In [4]: Distance(42).meters
0.0
Out[4]: 0.0

In [5]: Distance(42).km
Out[5]: 42.0

In [6]: Distance(42).miles
0.0
Out[6]: 0.0
```

Why is `self.km` set to 0 when I try to read it from `miles` and `meters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cdef double distance, miles, meters, km
```

You have two definitions of `miles`, `meters` and `km` - the properties and the cdef variables with the same name.

Cython looks to be reading from the cdef variables, which will be automatically zero initialized.

Comment: Why does `km` work but `miles` and `meters` don't?

Comment: When you call it from Python, it doesn't know about the Cython cdef variables so it uses the property. However, within Cython it prefers the cdef variable instead